# SQL join special like in

Tags: sql, select, join, sql-server-2008-r2

i use SQL 2008 R2

i have a table ORDER

```
ORDER_ID LABEL QUAINTITY IS_CLOSED
1        oooo  5         true  
2        pppp  6         true
3        oooo  5         true
4        iiii  9         false
```

Table COMMANDE

```
COMMAND_ID THE_ODER 
1          1_3
2          2
```

what i want

```
ORDER_ID LABEL QUAINTITY THE_ODER
1        oooo  5          1_3 
2        pppp  6          2  
3        oooo  5          1_3 
4        iiii  9
```

how can i joint this two table ?

somehow like where ODER.ORDER_ID in COMMAND.THE_ORDER

i know this not a good architecture and violence the norm. but i got to deal with it.

Comment: It seems you're trying to put multiple values into one field via separator to store link 1:many or many:many. It's the common mistake in DB architecture. Use linking table instead.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i m using SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `order` is a bad name for a table.  It is a SQL reserved word.  `orders` would be better.

You can do this with an arcane join.  Basically, look for the `order_id` in the list of `the_oder`:

```
select o.ORDER_ID, o.LABEL o.QUAINTITY, c.THE_ODER
from "order" o left outer join
     commande c
     on instr('_'||c.the_oder||'_', '_'||cast(o.order_id as varchar2(255))||'_') > 0
```

The above uses Oracle syntax for the string concatenation and finding a substring.  Unfortunately, you cannot use `like` easily because `'_'` is a wildcard character for `like`.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, you would do:

```
select o.ORDER_ID, o.LABEL o.QUAINTITY, c.THE_ODER
from "order" o left outer join
     commande c
     on charindex('_'+cast(o.order_id as varchar(255))+'_', '_'+c.the_oder+'_') > 0
```

Comment: thanks you, but do you have in SQL 2008 R2 instead of Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

In this example rather than having a delimited set of values to check against you should simply have a link table to store the values in. It should look something like this:

Table COMMANDE

```
COMMAND_ID ODRER_ID 
1          1
1          3
2          2
```

From here you can join to this table to retrieve the information you need.

Comment: i know this the best way, but i already got the data like that. so i have to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select order_id,label,quantity
from orders
left join
select * from command
on orders.orderID=command.commandid
```